# Dividing by a higher number returning 0

Tags: c#

When I try to do this

```
double test = ((2 / 7) * 100);
```

it returns 0.

Does anybody know why this is and how to work around it?

Thanks

Comment: Because it is **integer** division.

Comment: Fastest flurry of answers I've ever seen roll in.. keep in mind you can use "d" to signify doubles, such as this: `((2d / 7d) * 100)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2 / 7 is integer division, and will return 0. Try this instead

```
2.0 / 7

(double) 2 / 7
```

Answer (score 5):

You're dividing *integers*.

If you want a non-integer result, at least one operand must be a float or double (or decimal).

You can do that by adding `.00` to any of the literals to create a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing integers, so `2 / 7` becomes already `0`. Just try `2.0 / 7.0` and you'll get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing integer division because all the operands are integers.

To fix it, change at least one the operands to doubles like this:

```
double test = ((2.0 / 7.0) * 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer math, and only converting to `double` when you have the final result.

```
2 / 7 = 0
```

while

```
2.0 / 7.0 = 0.285714285714285
```

Do the math with `double` values:

```
double test = ((2.0 / 7.0) * 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of division. A division of two int numbers returns int number truncating any decimal points. Hence the result of the operation 2/7 will be 0.

It should be something like this:

double test = ((2.0 / 7.0) * 100.0);