# How to calculate the average in C#, I couldn't find the error. It is compiled successfully but I am not getting the result

Tags: c#

I made a program to calculate the average of marks in three subjects. There is no compilation error but when I run the program it is just showing that "your marks is {0} and grade is F".

Kindly have a glance and guide me if something went wrong.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace marksrange
    {
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b, c;

        //entering the marks
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the quiz score out of 20 : ");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the mid-term score out of 30 : ");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the final exam score out of 100: ");
        c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //calculating the average
        int avg = (((a + b + c) / 150)*100);

        //checking the grades
        if ((avg > 90))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Result is {0} and the grade is A", avg);

        }
        else if ((avg > 70) && (avg < 90))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Result is {0} and the grade is B", avg);

        }
        else if ((avg > 50) && (avg < 70))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Result is {0} and the grade is C", avg);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Result is {0} and the grade is F", avg);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: "your marks is {0} and grade is F" ... Does your program try to tell you something :)

Comment: There are many questions about why "C# division always gives zero"... I don't think I found the best one for duplicate - if it does not cover your problem completely make sure to provide details by updating your post (and hopefully simplify sample/remove "thank you notes").

Comment: please cut me some slack sir... i just started programming in c# a week ago... you get silly problems when you  are a novice..... :)

Comment: the reference that you have provided, it just seemed advanced to me....I haven't even seen something like this while studying.. maybe after a while those lines will make sense to me..... thanks anyway :)

Comment: Here is one without any extra text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710926/dividing-by-a-higher-number-returning-0

Answer (score 1):

When we make a division with integers, a/b, when a is less than b the result is 0. This is your problem.

Specifically this quantity `(a + b + c)` is less than 150. In order to fix this, you could cast either the result of the addition or the 150 to a float:

```
(a + b + c) / (float)150
```

In summary, you should do the following:

```
float avg = (((a + b + c) / (float)150)*100);
```

Comment: Or just write 150.0f instead of 150. `150` defaults to an int, `150.0` defaults to a double, and `150.0f` is a float.

Comment: thanks...... everything is ON now... thanks again

Comment: Or multiple the sum by 100 before dividing by 150.