# When trying to work out a percentage of correct answers i always end up with 0%. can anyone tell me why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a winforms app of a quiz and i am trying to work out the overall percentage of correct answers however i always end up with 0%, can anyone tell me why?

```
class calculatePercentage
{
    public static int totalPercentage;

    public static void calculate()
    {
        totalPercentage = (Program.totalScore/45*100);
    }
}
```

i have tried using an int, decimal, double, float however i am still getting the same result.

Program.totalScore is the number of correct answers overall,
45 is the total number of questions.

e.g (30/45)*100 = 67% rounded.

When i do this calculation on a calculator it works out correct, but not in code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cast all of the numbers to decimal or float before calculating.

Comment: If general answer I've linked as duplicate does not explain everything please consider searching (https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20divide%20return%20zero) for existing answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710926/dividing-by-a-higher-number-returning-0 and then either update your post with specific details why it is different or ask new question.

Comment: To try and get you to answer your own question please run the following statements and compare the difference and then have a think about why.

    Console.WriteLine("(30/45)*100 = {0}", (30/45)*100);
    Console.WriteLine("(30/45.0)*100 = {0}", (30 / 45.0) * 100);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205490/why-do-these-division-equations-result-in-zero is probably a closer duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` calculations will always round down to the nearest whole number, so `Program.totalScore/45` will come out to zero, and multiplying that by zero still gives you zero. You could start with the multiplication first:

```
    totalPercentage = (100 * Program.totalScore) / 45;
```

... but be careful because this will always round down. If you want more accuracy, you'll need to use doubles and `Math.Round()`.

```
    totalPercentage = (int) Math.Round((100.0 * Program.totalScore) / 45);
```

Comment: Ok so in my example above it would be 66%, but i still get 0% in code

Comment: add .0 to either the 45 or 100.  That will make the calculation a double

Comment: @Sedwards: See my updated answer. `30/45` is 0 when you round down. Multiply that by zero, and it's still zero.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior this solved my issue as well as rounding to the nearest whole number.